If $R$ is Armendariz ring then its prime radical $P(R)$ is Armendariz or not?
First let us write about the definitions of some terms.
Armendariz ring : A ring $R$ is said to be Armendariz if whenever $f(x),g(x)\in R[x]$ satisfy $f(x)g(x)=0$ then $a_ib_j=0$ for all $i,j$. Here $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i,g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j$.
Prime radical of a ring : Intersection of all prime ideals of $R$ denoted by $P(R)$ is prime radical of $R$.
Now I am trying to prove or disprove (because I have not found any details in present literature) whether $P(R)$ is Armendariz or not. Although in this paper in example 13, it is proved that if $P(R)$ and $R/P(R)$ is Armendariz then $R$ need not be Armendariz. I am trying to prove its converse.
So let us start the proof : Let $R$ be an Armendariz ring. Now we have to prove $P(R)$ is Armendariz. Take two polynomials $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^na_ix^i,g(x)=\sum_{j=0}^mb_jx^j$ in $P(R)[x]$ where $a_i,b_j\in P(R)$. Suppose $f(x)g(x)=0$. Then how can I proceed?

Subrings of Armendariz rings are Armendariz. Think about $P(R)$ as a subring of $R$.

Okay, I understand this. But what about $R/P(R)$, is $R/P(R)$ also Armendariz or not.
